# Posts loading bug

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, network-profile

I noticed that clicking multiple times on one these tabs which is not selected adds up the loading GIF (in the profile page):

[image: Tabs]

Here is an image of it happening:

[image]

Its hard to explain whats happening so here is a GIF:

[image: GIF]

This behavior is noticed by me in all SE sites.
Try it yourself. Open any profile (with some posts) on any network, and start clicking.
<sub>Produced on Chrome V76 - Windows 10 (64 bit)</sub>

#### Update:

This can also be reproduced with other dialogs and tabs which involve the GIF loading. I reproduced it with the *close*, & *flag* question dialog as well.